# How to insert multiple sheets of Excel data into one table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, powershell, bcp

I have written a PowerShell script to download Excel data from a website:

```
## Download the NSCC-MPID-Directory.xls from website
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.webclient
$source = "http://www.dtcc.com/~/media/Files/Downloads/client-center/NSCC/NSCC-MPID-Directory.xls"
$destination = "C:\LSC\NSCC_MPID\NSCC-MPID-Directory.xls"
$webclient.downloadfile($source, $destination)
$filename = "NSCC-MPID-Directory.xls"
```

I want to write a `bcp` command to insert the Excel data into a table in my SQL Server database. But there are multiple sheets in the Excel file, and the following `bcp` will not work:

```
bcp SIAC.dbo.NSCC_MPID in $filename  -S database1 -T -c -q -m9999
```

Furthermore, I wonder if there is a way to get the sheet name in a separate column or I could insert each sheet's data into a different table. Because different sheets have the same format of data :

[image: dataset]

But they have different category which is shown in the sheet name like this:

[image: multiple sheet name]

I want to separate them in one table or insert them in the same table but create another column named category, for example "OTC"

I am really confused about how to deal with this... would anyone give me some suggestion about this? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried exporting the data to csv (https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/242589/sql-bcp-export-to-csv-file) and then use `Import-CSV` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee176874(v=technet.10)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this:

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

You can define `-Worksheetname`, also the module allows you to directly `ConvertFromExcelToSQLInsert`.

For instance, `ConvertFrom-ExcelToSQLInsert TableName .\testSQLGen.xlsx -WorksheetName OTC` would generate the insert statements for your OTC sheet, going into the TableName table.

Comment: Hi Jacob, could you give me an example how to use convert the sheet name in a new column when inserting into SQL server.. i could not find the code... Thanks

Comment: Try `ConvertFrom-ExcelToSQLInsert TableName .\testSQLGen.xlsx -WorksheetName OTC`. @Rachel this generates the SQL inserts for the OTC worksheet.